# Bind/event gives error 'int' object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to understand how bind and events work in python.  For example I've created 3 tiles and would like to be able to change the color of one of the tiles but cannot understand or figure out where I'm going wrong.  I keep getting:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bind'.
```

Below is the code and thanks in advance:

```
import tkinter

def main():

    root = tkinter.Tk()

    title = tkinter.Label(root, text="Test Window")
    title.pack()


    canvas= tkinter.Canvas(root, background='green', width = 300, height = 300)

    tile1=canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill = 'magenta')
    tile2=canvas.create_rectangle(100,0, 200,100, fill = 'blue')
    tile3=canvas.create_rectangle(200,0, 300,100, fill = 'blue')

    canvas.pack()

    def change_square(event):
        event.configure(background = 'blue')

    tile1.bind("<Button-1>", change_square(tile1))

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: iCodez actually fixed the problem before removing his comment. What I'm trying to truly grasp is how to select tile1, tile2, or tile3 for specific events which is why I did all the screwy stuff with trying to pass tile1 as an argument, etc I'll take a look at your link.. thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemconfigure` will change the colour:

```
def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    title = tkinter.Label(root, text="Test Window")
    title.pack()

    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, background='green', width=300, height=300)

    s1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='magenta')

    s2 = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 0, 200, 100, fill='blue')
    s3 = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 0, 300, 100, fill='blue')

    canvas.pack()

    def change_square(event):
        canvas.itemconfigure(s1, fill="blue")

    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", change_square)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you want to change the middle to black you would use:

```
canvas.itemconfigure(s2, fill="black")`
```

And so on.

If you want to change colour based on which you click this should work:

```
 def change_square(event):
        x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        sq = canvas.find_closest(x,y)[0]
        canvas.itemconfigure(sq, fill="black")


    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", change_square)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic.  This is closer to the answer I was looking for.  Given your code above, how could I get the s2 to change?  I tried adding canvas.itemconfigure(s2, fill="red") to see what happens when I click on s2. It ends up changing the color of both s1 and s2.  Is it possible to select them individually and have their colors change individual.  This is why I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to pass the s1,s2, or s3 objects as a parameter in change_square.  I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @Rinzler, I'll take a look at the other stackoverflow question you referenced.  Thanks again for all your efforts guys.  I'll try to figure this out myself and if I get stuck I'll ask another question.  For now though your answer gets me one step closer Padraic so thanks!

Comment: @Cosi, it should only change one item when you click, whichever one you specify. You basically want to click on individual parts of the canvas and have then change colour?

Comment: Ya it's really strange for some reason as soon as I click any tile it fills all the tiles to their designated fill color.  No worries.. I'll trie @Rinzler's link and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cosi, no worries, try the edit and see if it is closer to what you want

Comment: You can attach bindings to individual canvas items with the `tag_bind` method, FWIW. This would allow you to set individual bindings, and pass the item id as part of the callback using lambda or functools.partial.

Comment: Your latest edit worked Padraic.  I really am going to have to go over http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method ... they're just so much I'm clueless about here.